# Inherited form does not show correctly in design view

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2008, devexpress-windows-ui

I have a simple base form that has no UI controls in the design view. I have declared few textbox controls that have protected modifier and are used in both the parent code behind and as UI controls in the design view of the sub class that inherits the parent class.

Basically you see an empty form in the parent class's design view and a form with controls in the sub class's design view. The application compiles and runs as expected.

The problem is I keep getting a:

```
"No context registered. Use the 'RegisterContext' method or the 'spring/context' section from your configuration file"
```

when I try to open up the form. I know this was working a week ago. I did play around a bit with Spring.NET configurations but I am sure I have reverted everything back. If there was a problem that would show up during runtime anyway.

I debugged with another instance of VS to see what the problem is and it shows an issue as Spring.NET not being able to resolve a baseDao class. If I let the subclass inherit from System.Windows.Forms  only, there is no issue opening the the sub class in the design view. This is very strange. I did however manage to create another base class with a different name and subclass it. I have tried deleting the files from the solution and removed the references inside the project file. That did not help. Now if I rename the files, that won't work either.

Can anyone suggest anything here? VB.NET + Visual Studio 2008. The base form inherits from DevExpress Form v 11.1

**EDIT:** It's got nothing to do with DevExpress controls as changing the base form to inherit Windows.Forms.Form makes no difference

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this issue was adding this to the base form's load event handler.

```
If (Me.DesignMode) Then
        Return
 End If
```

Comment: This is exactly the correct answer. Solved my issue.